# What is the problem with Broward County Fl election results?

Tags: united-states, voting, florida

Press reports say that Broward County is still "counting ballots", I assume they really mean that the optical scanning machines are still reading the ballots and tabulating the votes for each candidate and issue.

I further assume that these optical scanners are located at one central location, and that election board employees are feeding the scanners.  (unlike at my precinct in Ohio where there are scanners at each polling place and the voter actually feeds his/her ballot into the scanner).

I see that the Broward County ballot is actually 5 pieces of paper, (10 pages of ballot) and I surmise that all ballots in the county are not the same (may be some very local issues (sub-county level voting). So it may be necessary to group ballots by precinct when counting votes.

So is the problem largely a deficiency in the number of scanning devices? Or is there some other mechanical problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Sun Sentinel in Florida says

> Why was the vote counting going so slowly? When counting resumed Thursday, tens of thousands of ballots remained to be processed, long after other counties had everything counted and results reported to the state. Broward elections chief Snipes blamed the volume of mail-in ballots, many of which were received just before the 7 p.m. deadline on Tuesday.

The article also has some pictures to give a sense of scale of what they are dealing with, and how many people are working to count votes:

[image: 9 or so people working on 6 or so voting machines, so many boxes of votes]

[image: boxes and boxes of votes]

Note that mail in ballots have to be checked for legitimacy by committee:

[image: Supervisor of Elections Dr. Brenda Snipes, center, examines provisional ballots at the Broward County Supervisor of Elections Warehouse]

This also takes time.

https://www.sun-sentinel.com/news/politics/fl-ne-election-broward-turnout-thursday-20181108-story.html

The article continues, pointing out that "most" of the counting is done as of Friday.

[538](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/something-looks-weird-in-broward-county-heres-what-we-know-about-a-possible-florida-recount/) points out that there are supposed to be results given by noon today (Nov 10):

> Under Florida law, counties have to report unofficial election results to the secretary of state by Saturday at noon, ...

so expect to hear something today (results, or deadline extension).

Comment: Still leaves lingering questions. Are the in-person ballots tallied at the precinct level?  If so, then the only task for the committee is to check that mailed-in ballots are legitimate, then open those ballots and  scan those. Scanning should take almost no time, even if there are tens of thousands that have not yet been processed.  What may take some time is the voter validation process for mailed in ballots. But there is no real excuse here - see next

Comment: @BobE: Why should scanning take "almost no time"?  If each ballot is 10 pages, and scanning takes one second per page (counting loading, clearing paper jams, &c), then scanning 10,000 ballots takes more than a day.

Comment: @jamesqf - Are you assuming that the there is but **one** scanner?  Is that reasonable?

Comment: @BurnsBA - continuing - I'm inclined to think that the voter verification process is the time consuming segment.  Consider that on election day, there are people at the polls that check-in voters - they check that the would be voter is entitled to receive a ballot. They are performing the same function  that the "committee" is that are determining the validity of a mailed-in ballot.  I'll suggest that cadre of voting day validators may number in the hundreds. Why wouldn't the "committee" use these people to validate mailed-in ballots. They certainly should be qualified.

Comment: While processing votes in a committee may take time, it would be easy to count how many are waiting to be processed. Broward County failed to do that.

Comment: @Sjoerd They could not accurately "count" the number of mail-in ballots to be processed because: Overseas mail-in ballots are still being accepted and will be accepted until NOV 16.   Is there a state/county law (regarding how many mail-in and provisional ballots have not yet been validated) that the county "failed"?  Were those counts supposed to be announced daily? Hourly?  -- I would love to see the procedures published (either by the state or county) of the exact details of how mailed-in, faxed-in, and provisional ballots are to be processed.

Comment: @BobE The Nov 16 deadline must be wrong: that would be many days *after* the deadline to publish the results. We're talking about a recount here - there shouldn't be additional votes added after the first count has finished.

Comment: @Sjoerd "A 10-day extension exists for overseas voters. The overseas voter’s vote-by-mail ballot must be postmarked or dated by Election Day and received within 10 days of the election in order to be counted" (per Florida Statutes 100.191) [ https://dos.myflorida.com/elections/for-voters/voting/military-and-overseas-citizens-voting/ ]  So, should overseas votes that are due (deadlined) tomorrow be counted? And if those votes are tabulated, should those be included in the totals.

Comment: @BobE How many would you expect to be that late? Besides, totals could be posted, e.g. daily, even when not final. There is no excuse for hiding the total.

Comment: If your vote is one of those that arrives tomorrow, do you want it counted? I will grant you that these late arrivals will probably not impact who wins, but you surely would want you vote counted - yes?

Comment: In some way this reminds me of a football game being televised whose score is 20  to 13.  With two minutes to go, the network would like to move on to 60 minutes, the players are tired, the crowd at the stadium is cold and wet - in other words everybody wants to declare a winner and move on - but the game isn't over until the final whistle. Well, in this case the final whistle isn't blown until all the legitimate votes are tabulated and the state certifies that vote count.